# Confusion about the definition of smooth moving regions (Evans. Partial Differential Equation 2nd ed. appendices C.4.)

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations

In the appendices of Evans's book *Partial Differential Equations* 2nd ed., he has the following introduction on the section C.4. moving regions.

[image]

In the section before this, he does define what smooth boundary means for an open and connected set; however, I wonder what he means here for "a family of smooth, bounded regions $U(\tau)\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ that depend smoothly upon the parameter $\tau\in\mathbb{R}$." What is a smooth region, and how can a region depends smoothly on something? I appreciate any help in making this rigorous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $I\subset\Bbb{R}$ be an open interval, $U\subset\Bbb{R}^n$ an open set, and $\Phi:I\times U\to\Bbb{R}^n$ a map with whatever smoothness you like: $C^1,C^k,C^{\infty},C^{k,\alpha}$, mixed regularity in the two variables etc. Let us adopt the notation $\Phi_{t}(x);\Phi(t,x)$. Then, we call the family of sets $U(\tau):=\Phi_{\tau}[U]$ a smooth 1-parameter family of sets. Now, typically, one imposes the condition that for each $\tau\in I$, the set $\Phi_{\tau}[U]$ is open in $\Bbb{R}^n$ and the map $\Phi_{\tau}:U\to\Phi_{\tau}[U]\subset\Bbb{R}^n$ is a diffeomorphism onto its image (so it can be considered as a “time-dependent change of variables”).

You can of course generalize this: given three smooth manifolds $X,Y,Z$ and a smooth map $\Phi:X\times Y\to Z$, you can talk about a smooth parameter-dependent family of sets, namely $\Phi_x[Y]$ as $x$ varies in $X$ (so you think of $X$ as the space of paramaeters, and think of $\Phi_x[Y]$ as a copy of $Y$ sitting inside $Z$ (assuming $\Phi_x$ is a diffeomorphism onto its image)).

Answer (score 1):

**What is a smooth region?**

In the context you are working on, I assume that smoothness implies that the boundary of $U(\tau)$ is smooth for all $\tau$. That is, every point at the boundary has assigned a single tangent space. This is required in order to be able to integrate $$\int_{\partial U(\tau)} f\ \boldsymbol{v} \cdot \nu dS$$ over the boundary.

**How can a region depend smoothly on something?**

We say that a family of regions $U(\tau)$ depends smoothly on $\tau\in\mathbb{R}$ if there exists a diffeomorphism (smooth function) $f:\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n, \ (\tau,\boldsymbol{x})\mapsto f_\tau(\boldsymbol{x})$ such that $U(\tau) = f_\tau(U_0)$ (note that $f_0=Id$). We say then that the family $f_\tau$ of diffeomorphisms is smoothly transforming the region $U_0$ as we variate $\tau$.

Comment: Do we just require $f$ to be smooth? Since from my knowledge, diffeomorphism preserves dimension.

Comment: @HaoqingYu Yes, it suffices for $f$ to be smooth, but in that case we should further assume that $f_\tau$ is a diffeomorphism for all $\tau$.